# Kendo UI Grid Editor Template for Date

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to custom edit filed for KENDO UI grid with date.

I created grid like this:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TT.TT.Web.Models.ViewModel.WorkViewModel>()
                          .Name("gridAdd")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(work => 
                              work.Date).EditorTemplateName("WorkDate");
                          })
  )
```

Editor template look like this:

```
@model DateTime? 

    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("WorkDate")
        .Value(Model == null ? DateTime.Now.Date : @Model).Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
    )
```

And in TT.TT.Web.Models.ViewModel.WorkViewModel have this property:

```
[Display(Name = "Datum")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Everythink works, but when I click to edit date column, the value is always empty. I need to set default value due to value in non edit mode. Thanks!

When i look to DateTime modeli in editor:

```
@model DateTime? 

@Html.Raw(@Model)
```

The value is always: 01.01.0001 0:00:00 and it should be 11.07.1990

Comment: Are you just trying to set a default date for this property? If you are, you don't need a custom editor template. You can just set the default value on the schema instead.

Comment: public DateTime? Date { get; set; }, that should play better with Model == null ? DateTime.Now.Date : @Model, or else DateTime will have lowest possible value instead of being null